# How to Receive messages from quickblox_id not registered with createChat in Android?

Tags: java, android, quickblox

How to Receive messages from quickblox_id not registered with createChat in Android?
as titled.

editted:

```
public static void register_general_chat(final QBMessageListener<QBChat> callback) {
    privateChatManagerListener = new QBPrivateChatManagerListener() {
        @Override
        public void chatCreated(final QBPrivateChat privateChat, final boolean createdLocally) {
            NSLog("chatCreated.createdLocally=" + createdLocally);
            if (!createdLocally) {
                privateChat.addMessageListener(callback);
            }
        }
    };
    NSLog("chat_manager added");
    privateChatManager.addPrivateChatManagerListener(privateChatManagerListener);
}
```

Comment: explain your question clearly with code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first time receive a message in some chat - next callback will be fired:

```
QBPrivateChatManagerListener privateChatManagerListener = new QBPrivateChatManagerListener() {
    @Override
    public void chatCreated(final QBPrivateChat privateChat, final boolean createdLocally) {
        if(!createdLocally){
            privateChat.addMessageListener(privateChatMessageListener);
        }
    }
};
QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager().addPrivateChatManagerListener(privateChatManagerListener);
```

And then messages will come to QBMessageListener

More info here http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Chat_in_1-1_private_dialog

Comment: Many thanks~~~ btw, this portion of code had never been called, no matter how I tried.

Comment: What do you see in logs when somebody sends you a message?

Comment: The problem is solved.  Igor's the answer.  It turns out that I clear all the log and have a focused check with all the codes, and found that the part of program is not called in some logical flow.  Many thanks for everyone~~~! pity though i don't have enough reputation to give an UP

Comment: if one user is  signing in to chat and at that time other user sending him message so this method chatCreated() is not working means in even executing # Igor Khomenko